# Adding data to database in parts (asp.net)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a couple of pages for booking and each page saves data. For example page one adds the destination to the database, page two is selecting amount of passengers.

I have a table to store all this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] (
[cardNumber ] NCHAR (10) NULL,
[Cost]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
[Passengers]  NCHAR (10) NULL,
[Destination] NCHAR (10) NULL
);
```

On the destination page I am using the following code to input the destination to the database:

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();
        string insert = "insert into Transactions (Destination) values (@Destination)";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insert, conn);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", DropDownList1.SelectedItem);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString()); 
    }

    Response.Redirect("Booking.aspx"); 
}
```

On the next page I have relatively the same code to enter the amount of passengers:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        string insert = "insert into Transactions (Passengers) values (@Passengers)";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insert, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passengers", DropDownList1.SelectedItem);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }

    Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx");

}
```

But after doing this no data gets entered into the database. If anyone knows of anyway that I can enter data into the database one piece at a time please let me know.

If it can’t be done this way and there is a much better way of doing this again please let me know.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Move `Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx");` after `conn.Close();` If en exception is thrown, the `Response.Write` will hide by the redirect.

Comment: what happens when you run the code and use breakpoints alsorefactor the Sql Objects and wrap them around a `using(){ }` also try issuing a `Commit` and see if that helps also you are aware that clicking the button causes a `PostBack` whats does the `Page_Load` code look like for each of the pages

Comment: I'm gona be straight with you i don't know what half of that stuff means. the page load void is empty though and thanks Kalten I've done that so it doesn't redirect when there is error.

Comment: in the Debugger what is the value of `DropDownList1.SelectedItem` here is something a hint look at the following 
you want the text value you need `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passengers", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);`

Comment: The options of the dropdownlist is for the first page is stuff like cinema, bowlplex etc (just example data). The options for the second page are just numbers but they are in text format so, one, two, three etc. i will try changing selected item to text and see what happens

Comment: The problem is that you are attempting to do too many things that you do not know how to do at once.  You obviously don't know how to create a table in SQL, nor how to save something to a database, or how to avoid connection leaks, or how to do proper exception handling, or how to control flow between pages.  When all of those things are wrong at the same time, you are not going to be able to get out of the mess.  Do one and only one thing at a time.  Only move on to the next when you know how to do the previous step correctly.

Comment: I changed it to text, it adds the data now, thanks :) Problem is though it's doing what I expected it to do it's added destination to a new row and passengers to a new row (not on the same row) and left all the other fields as null, I’ll have a look at a different way of doing this but thank you :)

Comment: I explain how to do this to a single row below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a dedicated primary key column on your table, I recommend an autoincrementing integer.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]
(
    [ID]          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [CardNumber]  NCHAR (10) NULL,
    [Cost]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
    [Passengers]  NCHAR (10) NULL,
    [Destination] NCHAR (10) NULL
);
```

Then, use stored procedures, not ad-hoc SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TransactionSave
(
    @ID int = null,
    @CardNumber nchar(10) = null,
    @Cost nchar(10) = null,
    @Passengers nchar(10) = null,
    @Destination nchar(10) = null
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ExistingID int
SELECT @ExistingID = ID FROM Transaction WHERE ID = @ID

IF @ExistingID is null
BEGIN
     --Insert
     INSERT INTO Transaction (CardNumber, Cost, Passengers, Destination)
     VALUES (@CardNumber, @Cost, @Passengers, @Destination)

     SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT) AS 'TransactionID'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     --Update
     UPDATE Transaction
     SET
         CardNumber = ISNULL(@CardNumber, CardNumber),
         Cost = ISNULL(@Cost, Cost),
         Passengers = ISNULL(@Passengers, Passengers),
         Destination = ISNULL(@Destination, Destination),
     WHERE ID = @ExistingID

     SELECT @ExistingID AS 'TransactionID'
END

END
```

Then, in your code behind, you need to retain the ID value of the Transaction you are working on, to be sure you're updating the proper row:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int transactionID = hfID.Value;

    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TransactionSave", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", transactionID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passengers", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

            transactionID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            hfID.Value = transactionID;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try now and see what happens give me a while to read through first though so I get an idea of what’s happening :)

Comment: Sounds good. The short story is that you need to retain something to denote 'which row' you're working with. The row's ID is returned by that proc, and you can capture it with `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`. Then, you'll probably want to redirect once the necessary information is entered.

Comment: Note that this approach is somewhat atypical; the 'normal route' to go is to have the form on the UI require a complete 'row' of data, then click a button and perform the row's insert all at once. However, 'atypical' does not mean 'impossible'.

Comment: It works cheers dude :) had a few errors and such but after a bit of google work it's done thank you very much :)

Comment: Were any of the errors with the code displayed here? It did assume you add a HiddenField `hfID`. If you have any more questions, let me know.